# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_page_projects' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

Created first project model and populated it with some data, then tried to add profile model to it (no data there) through foreign key and while trying to do a migration for linking profile model with projects model getting an error:

*django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_page_projects' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: main_page_projects.profile_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in main_page_profile.id.*

Value nr 1 was picked during the makemigration:

*It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'profile' to projects without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:*
*1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)*
*2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.*

I googled around and looked also stackoverflow, probably if I delete migration files and sqlite3 database then migrations should work, but I would like to know how to make it to work without deleting migration files and database. If populate profile then migration also works, but why it won't create a link with default values?

What should I do differently or where I go wrong?

Using Django 4.0.2 and Python 3.9.5

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name='Email')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Description')
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_picture')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'


class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Name')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    tech = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Description')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Project'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Projects'
```

Projects migration and Profile migration code

**Projects migration**

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Projects',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Name')),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(unique=True)),
                ('tech', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('description', models.TextField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Description')),
                ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**Profile migration**

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main_page', '0003_projects_image'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Profile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('full_name', models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='Email')),
                ('bio', models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Description')),
                ('profile_picture', models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_picture')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Profile',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Profiles',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

**Foreign key relation migration**

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.2 on 2022-02-11 08:05

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main_page', '0004_profile'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='projects',
            name='profile',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='1', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='main_page.profile'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not create an entry in a database table (or modify one by adding a field via migrations) with a ForeignKey that points to a non existing entry on the target table ("Profile" in your case). It does not make sense - so you get the integrity error.
Leave away the default=1 and make it "blank=True, null=True" so you can leave it empty upon creation or during migration.